# Can't seem to catch the MySQL error with try catch block in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I post data via ajax to my controller which does some validating and sends it off to the model. My table has a unique index to prevent duplicates. Unique inserts work fine, my problem is I can't seem to catch the duplicate error and deal with it.

Model Code: 
function insert($data) {

```
    //die($this->db->last_query);

    try{
        $query = $this->db->insert('subscriber',$data);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
         echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }



    if($query){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

jQuery ajax call:
function runAjax() {

```
$('#theform').append('<p id="loading"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>' + 'images/loader.gif"/>');

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   cache: false,
   url: "<?php echo base_url();?>" + 'contact/mail',
   data: 'fname=' + $('#fname').val() + '&lname=' + $('#lname').val() + '&email=' + $('#email').val(),
   success: function(msg){

   $('#response').remove();
   $('#theform').append('<p id="response">' + msg + '</p>');
   $('#loading').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
   },
   error: function(msg){
   $('#theform').append('<p id="response">' + msg + '</p>');
   }
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Errors from MySQL are not thrown as exceptions and hence you cannot catch them.**

Instead, if you query results null, you can print out the messages with db->_error_message() and db->_error_number() (http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/79950/#413830). As such, you could rewrite your code as follows:

```
    $query = $this->db->insert('subscriber',$data);

    if($query){
        return true;
    } else {
        $msg = $this->db->_error_message();
        $num = $this->db->_error_number();
        // Do something with msg and num
        return false;
    }
```

Also note **that `error` inside `$.ajax` is only called if there is an error performing the request.** Even though your database query fails, it still doesn't make the Ajax query fail. Hence, you will never the Ajax error.

I see two options here:

1) Make the HTTP request fail somehow (e.g. return HTTP 404 error).

2) Process your MySQL errors inside `success` method, instead of `error`:

```
success: function(msg){

   if ( msg == 'yoursuccessmessage' ) {
      // Handle success
   } else {
      // Handle error
   }
},
```

Comment: I tried that, but once the query fails, the ajax response is Object object. I the query fails I want to be able to give a custom message like,'you have already signed up'. Instead I just get Object object back.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it had some to do HTTP requests. I had to move the jQuery from an asset file and place into my document just to get it not to work the way I wanted. When it was in the asset file it wouldn't even run the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    $this->db->trans_start();

    $q = $this->db->query('SELECT qty as num FROM tbl_stock_materials WHERE smId = '.$smid);
    $row = $q->result();
    if($row->num < $qty)
    {
        $nQty = $qty - $row->num;
        $this->db->query('INSERT INTO tbl_qty_materials(qty, date_in, smId, cId, subId) VALUES('.$nQty.', "'.date('d-M-Y').'", '.$smid.', '.$cat.', '.$sub.')');    
    }

    $data = array(
        'qty'       =>      $qty
    );

    $this->db->where('smId', $smid);
    $up = $this->db->update('tbl_stock_materials', $data);

    $this->db->trans_complete();
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
    show_error($ex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..